# Delta Timestamp Parsing in R (Nanoseconds, Microseconds, Milliseconds)

Tags: r, time, timestamp, datetime-format, timedelta

I am working in R and need to change the timestamp from what I believe is nanosecond precision to either microsecond precision or millisecond precision (I believe it needs to be milliseconds or only three digits past the decimal).

[Example of two of the timestamps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PCE62.png)

```
"2019-03-02D00:00:12.214841000"
```

Part of the difficulty is I don't think there is a package like `lubridate` to handle it. I'm not sure if I need to use a regular expression to extract the seconds and then transform the nanoseconds to milliseconds. I'm open to any suggestions.

Also, how do you recommend dealing with the `D`? I was thinking I should use `gsub("D", "-", df$timestamp)` and maybe then a package like `lubridate` could parse the timestamp even with the nanosecond precision?

Answer (score 3):

You can use `as.POSIXct` after `gsub("D", " ", x)`:

```
as.POSIXct(gsub("D", " ", "2019-03-02D00:00:12.214841000"))
```

You can still work with millisecond precision afterwards:

```
dt <- as.POSIXct(gsub("D", " ", "2019-03-02D00:00:12.214841000"))
dt
[1] "2019-03-02 00:00:12 CET"
for(i in 1:1000) dt <- dt - 0.001
dt
[1] "2019-03-02 00:00:11 CET"
```

If you want to display those milliseconds you can use `format`:

```
format(dt, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS3")
[1] "2019-03-02 00:00:11.214"
format(dt - 1E-3, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS3")
[1] "2019-03-02 00:00:11.213"
format(dt - 10E-3, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS3")
[1] "2019-03-02 00:00:11.204"
```

Comment: How could I modify this code so if I wanted three digits of precision so it's rendered in milliseconds like `2019-03-02D00:00:12.214` ?

Comment: Thank you! The bit of code `format(dt, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS3")` from your edit works like a charm. I was curious what the additional two lines of code were for: `dt - 1E-3` and `10E-3` parts. I took the nanoseconds for the first few rows and put them into a millisecond converter and the first line of code without the `1E-3` is spot on. Just curious what's going on with the other two adjustments.

Comment: The only other problem I'm having is that at this point it's not a datetime object and is being treated as a character. I'm not sure how to transform the date into an appropriate date-time object.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the library `nanotime` which is related to `integer64`(really high precision float)

```
library(nanotime)
x<-nanotime("2019-03-02T00:00:12.214841000+00:00")
```

As you can see, you need to change `D` for `T` and add `00:00`to the end, but that is easyly done as symbolrush showed you.

```
x<-nanotime(paste0(gsub("D", "T", "2019-03-02D00:00:12.214841000"), "+00:00"))
```

See more here:

http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/nanotime.html

Comment: Thank you for the answer. You guys are all awesome.