# Convert nanoseconds to hh:mm:ss.ms in R

Tags: r, timestamp

How can I convert a nanosecond digit to hh:mm:ss.ms  The nanoseconds is from midnight, if the date part comes to be 1970-1-1, it is fine, I can ignore it. If you could help that'll be great.

So far I have tried this -

```
x = 38880001000000

as.POSIXct(x, origin = "1970-01-01",tz="GMT")
```

But getting output- "1234028-03-08 13:46:40 GMT", whilst I should get 1970-01-01 10:48:00.001000

Could you please guide me ?

Comment: `as.POSIX` needs the number of seconds rather than nanoseconds, so just divide accordingly. `as.POSIXct(x/1e9, origin = "1970-01-01",tz="GMT")`

Comment: Also maybe look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64506945/how-to-safely-import-timestamps-with-nanosecond-precision